# Get active Window in UI

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using a Vaadin-UI with a servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class, widgetset = "widgetsets.MyWidgetSet")
public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet {

}

@Theme("mytheme")
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Push
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("myView", MyView.class);
        // add some other views
        navigator.navigateTo("myView");
        setNavigator(navigator);
    }
}

public class MyView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
         // init UI stuff
    }
}
```

It works fine so far but what I want to do now, is to use the [ConfirmDialog Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/confirmdialog) from inside my view. My problem is that all of the `ConfirmDialog.show()` methods require a `Window` as a parameter. How can I obtain the active `Window` object isnide `View` or `UI` classes? `UI.getCurrent().getWindows()` is empty and all the examples I found use an `Application` class.

Comment: ConfirmDialog 2.0.5 takes an UI for the show param and no window? What version are you on?

Comment: @cfrick 1.0.1 is the only one in the `http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons` Maven repository.

Comment: well i got my 2.0.5 by that url, ymmv.  i assume then that v1 wants a window to render into.  Vaadin won't create windows by default so unless you have already created your own, can you just pass a new one?

Comment: @cfrick That seems like an ugly workaround. I'll try using the newest version. Am I right assuming that `Window` and it's concepts are deprecated in Vaadin 7?

Comment: @cfrick works fine with 2.0.5. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1 of the addon uses an existing window (create one and pass it, as Vaadin only has Page and UI by default, a Window is just an component). With version 2 of the addon you pass only the UI, where the dialog (which subclasses Window) will show itself.